# Programmatically parse and edit C++ Source Files

Tags: c++, parsing

I want to programmatically parse and edit C++ source files. I need to change/add code in certain sections of code (i.e. in functions, class blocks, etc). I would also (preferably) be able to get comments as well.

Part of what I want to do can be explained by the following piece of code:

```
CPlusPlusSourceParser cp = new CPlusPlusSourceParser(“x.cpp”);  // Create C++ Source Parser Object
CPlusPlusSourceFunction[] funcs = cp.getFunctions();  // Get all the functions

for (int i = 0; i &lt funcs.length; i++) {  // Loop through all functions
    funcs[i].append(/* … code I want to append …*/);  // Append some code to function 
}
cp.save(); // Save new source
cp.close(); // Close file
```

How can I do that?

I’d like to be able to do this preferably in Java, C++, Perl, Python or C#. However, I am open to other language API’s.

Comment: Something sounds wrong when you want to add the same code to the end of every function...

Comment: I don't want to add the same code everytime, I was just using the above as an example

Comment: @Mark: Depends on what its for. Could be e.g. for some aspect oriented c++.

Comment: This is VERY difficult to do.  If it could be done we'd have awesome c++ refactoring and intellisense tools.  We don't have any and there is huge demand for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to [AST from C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239722/ast-from-c-code)

If your comfortable with Java antlr can easily parser your code into an abstract syntax tree, and then apply transformation to that tree.  A default AST transform is to simply print out the original source.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any parser generator tool to generate a c++ parser for you, but first you have to get the CFG (context free grammar) for C++ , check [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/)

Edit:

Also [Antlr supports a lot of target languages](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets)

Comment: While there is an ANTLR C++ parser, I don't know of anyone that has used it for something production.  And I don't think it produces a symbol table, without which you really can't do anything with C++.

Answer (score 2):

You need a working grammar and parser for C++ which is, however, not too easy as this [can't be constructed with most parser generators out there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Parsing_and_processing_C.2B.2B_source_code). But once you *have* a parser you can actually take the abstract syntax tree of the program and alter it in nearly any way you want.

Comment: After yo uhave an abstract syntax tree, you will need a symbol table so you know the meaning of symbols. And this is extremely hard to get right.  ASTs are NOT enough.

Comment: @Ira: The OP sounded like s?he just wanted to append some code to functions. If that doesn't reference variables it should still be doable. Also it might be that they have a good enough assumption on how the code looks.

Answer (score 2):

The Mozilla project has [a tool that does this](http://blog.mozilla.com/tglek/2009/11/06/fsoss-dehydra-update/).

---

The [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) is now somewhat famous for doing a good job analyzing and rewriting C++.  [Stroustrup wrote a paper](http://stroustrup.com/gdr-bs-macis09.pdf) about a research project at Texas A&M, but I don't think it's been released.

Answer (score 2):

A [robust C++ parser](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) is available with our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html). It parses a variety of C++ dialects including ANSI, GNU 3/4, MSVS6 and MSVisual Studio 2005 and managaged C++.

It builds ASTs and symbol tables (the latter is way harder than you might think).  You can navigate the ASTs, transform into different valid C++ programs, and regenerate code including comments.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) project, its a open source project, to parse and document several programming languages, C++ included.  I believe  using this project's lexer will get you more than half the way

Answer (score 1):

In a C# -- or general .net -- approach, you might be able to get some use out of the [C++/CLI CodeDOM provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualc.cppcodeprovider_members.aspx) -- having not used the C++ version of this type, I don't know how well it would handle code that is template heavy.