# Expression parsing in C

Tags: c, expression-trees

Is there a tool that helps you visualise how a C expression is parsed. In other words can someone see the expression tree

Comment: Are you looking for a C expression parser *in C* or will any language do?

Comment: Any language would do, although a GUI showing the expression tree would be fantastic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AST from C code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239722/ast-from-c-code)

Comment: I doubt that this is a duplicate of [AST From C Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239722/ast-from-c-code). This question explicitly asks about **visualization** (of the AST), the other does not. The OP might want to indicate this by adjusting the question's title.

Answer (score 2):

You can give [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/works/index.html) a try, it has a nice front-end(ANTLRWorks) for visualization and there is a c99 for it avialable from the same site.

It will probably take a little work to visual things as you want them, but all the tools are already there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ROSE](http://www.rosecompiler.org/).  I have found that making it work was a bit cumbersome -- not the easiest piece of software to build from sources, and I doubt they have a binary release. There are a set of tools and library support for making pdf/graphviz dump of the AST.  And then there's a tool called roseQt which you might find useful.